# Django models: Set default relative to another field

Tags: django, django-models

I am building an app using Django 1.10 as backend. 
Is it possible to set a model field's default relative to another model from the same instance?

I specifically need to set `second_visit's` default to be 3 weeks after the `first_visit`

```
class SomeModel(models.Model): 
    first_visit = models.DateField()
    second_visit = models.DateField(default= second_visit_default)

    def second_visit_default(self):
        # Set second_visit to 3 weeks after first_visit
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot assign a default value on a field dependent on another before having a model instance. To achieve the same you can override the `save()` method of the model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.second_visit = self.first_visit + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Warning: this is not the same as having a default. This will break any subsequent saves of the model where the user will actually want to set an explicit value in that field.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `save` or use`pre_save`

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(pre_save, sender=SomeModel)
def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.second_visit = # Set second_visit to 3 weeks after instance.first_visit
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is a late answer, but [@BjornW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817044/bjornw) addresses a valid concern in [the comment on the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343531/django-models-set-default-relative-to-another-field#comment111899138_41343655) that is not addressed in the 2 provided answers (at the time of writing): Overwriting `save` is not the same thing as setting a default value; a default value only takes effect once, at the first instance creation, while modifying `save` affects every subsequent modification of an existing instance as well. The [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41343682/1622937) suffers from the same deviation of the principle of a default value.*

Providing a default value relative to other attributes of `self` is not (yet?) possible, however you can use the [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#pre_save) signal to set a default value for a field that is relative to other fields.

Here would be an example:

```py
# signals.py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
# do all necessary imports e.g.:
from .models import SomeModel

@receiver(pre_save, sender=SomeModel)
def set_default_second_visit(sender, instance, raw, **kwargs):
    """
    Set default value for `second_visit`
    """
    if instance.pk is None:
        instance.second_visit = instance.second_visit or instance.first_visit + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3)
```

A note might be at hand:

It is not that the `pre_save` signal is sent only once. Actually, it is sent whenever an instance of `SomeModel` is saved, i.e. also if an existing entry from the db is modified. The line `if instance.pk is None:` is present and necessary exactly for this reason: it makes sure that that **the value is set only if the object does not yet exist in the database** (i.e has no primary key yet).

Comment: Problem is, bulk methods (e.g. `bulk_create()` or `bulk_update()`) don't send pre_save signals or call the `.save()` method, rendering this soltion inadequate :(