# Django Models: Using DateField to set parameters in FileField

Tags: python, django, file, file-upload, django-models

**Background:** I'm am creating Django app to manage receipts. The user will create a new `Receipt`, fill out some fields with information on the receipt (i.e. cost, items, date purchased, etc.), and upload a copy of the receipt for storage.

**Problem:** I want to store the receipt *.pdf files in a folder based on the purchase date the user enters, however, I do not have access to `self.date.strftime('%Y %B')` until after instantiation.

**Example Code:**

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    item = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    scan = models.FileField(upload_to='scans/{d}/'.format(d=date.strftime('%Y %B')),
                           max_length=100)
```

**Research:**

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41343531/1713185) needs to do something similar, but for a different reason. The answer that he got, was this it was not possible without overriding the `save()` method. How would that work with file uploads?

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1190697/1713185) specifically addresses how to set the parameters of `FileField` with a function; however, it does not involve using fields from the not-yet-complete model (i.e. `Receipt`).

What are my work-around options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django FileField with upload\_to determined at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of that question. My question specifically relates to using a models fields to set its own fields.

Comment: The above question have a perfect answer for your problem. Make a function which uses your datefield and returns you the absolute path for the file.

Comment: I don't believe so? Would my receipt not have to complete initialization before it is available to other functions? In the question you linked, he is returning information from `instance`, a model that already exists.

Comment: No it really don&#39;t have to be initialise to be available to other functions at least not in this case. Read both questions and answer carefully I am 100% sure that it will work for you.

Comment: Wow. I apologize, that does work!

Comment: Pleasure here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to change upload_to folder in runtime?

this function get the folder name:

```
def get_upload_to(instance, filename):
        dest = getattr(instance, 'upload_destination', 'scans')
        date = '/{d}/'.format(d=date.strftime('%Y %B')
        return '/'.join([dest, date])
```

and in upload field (models.py) call the function above:

```
file = models.FileField(
            upload_to=get_upload_to,
            null=True,
            blank=False
        )
```

and in model save after request in your view:

```
your_model = your_form.save(commit=False)
setattr(your_model, 'upload_destination', 'scans/')
your_model.save()
```

I hope that help's!